# Remove URL parameters JS ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a url that contains a parameter, which I want to remove. I have created an `if...else` condition, but I would like to improve it in ES6.

```
if ( window.location.search.indexOf('&submit')  > -1 ) {
    window.location = urlBase + '/' + window.location.search;
} else {
    window.location = urlBase + '/' + window.location.search + '&submit=1';
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would you hope that ES6 could improve in this code?

Comment: I want just know if possible to reduce this condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what your goal is, but here I've simply used `includes` and template literals.

```
if (window.location.search.includes('&submit')) {
    window.location = `${urlBase}/${window.location.search}`;
} else {
    window.location = `${urlBase}/${window.location.search}&submit=1`;
}
```